# Need to find the missing values from a string based on smoothening logic

Tags: python, curve-fitting, missing-data, smoothing

I have been given a string with digits and '*'(missing value) symbols and I have to replace the '*' symbols as explained:

```
Input1: "_,_,_,24"
Output1: 6,6,6,6
Input2: "40,_,_,_,60"
Output2: 20,20,20,20,20
Input4: "_,_,30,_,_,_,50,_,_"
Output4: 10,10,12,12,12,12,4,4,4
```

I have tried using basic for loops and if then else using 2 pivot points, but all of those approaches are challenged when the input string changes. I am finding it a bit challenging to design a generic system. I am not sure if there are any specific libraries in python with which I can do this or not. Suggestions in any form of pseudocode is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be enhanced for sure, but this do the trick :

```
string = "_,_,30,_,_,_,50,_,_"
output = string.split(',')

pos = 0
next_value = 0
last_pos = 0
last_value = 0

while pos < len(output):
    if output[pos] != '_' or (pos + 1 == len(output)):
        if output[pos] != '_':
            next_value = int(output[pos])
        else:
            next_value = 0
        new_value = (next_value + last_value) / (pos - last_pos + 1)
        for i in range(last_pos, pos + 1):
            output[i] = new_value
        last_value = new_value
        last_pos = pos
    pos += 1

print(output)
```

This produces an array of float : `[10.0, 10.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]`

**Extra information :**

- You have to find a non missing value by iterating on the array.
- When you found one, you add it to the last non missing value found (0
  otherwise) and and set the average on all the cells between the
  milestones (themselves included)
- When you reach the end of the array don't forget to do the same thing. The current value become 0, you add it to the previous one and share it again

If we take the following string `_,_,30,_,_,_,50,_,_`

First we find 30. We share it between the beginning and the current position.

We got : `10,10,10,_,_,_,50,_,_`

Then we find 50. The previous numerical value is 10. So we share 60 between the pos of 10 and 50 ( which is 5 cells)

We got : `10,10,12,12,12,12,12,_,_`

We reach the end of the array.

0 + 12 = 12 -> We share it between the current pos and the last 12 pos ( which is 3 cells)

We got `10,10,12,12,12,12,4,4,4`

Comment: Yes this does help..i had some trouble implementing this logic, but your code seems to do the trick. Thanks for this. I have tested it with a couple of use cases and all work fine. Thank you again..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```py
output = '10,,35,,,67,400'
output = output.split(',')
new_output = []

for i in output:
    if i != '':
        new_output.append(i)
```

Comment: Hi Jon..thank you for your code. However my requirement is a bit different. let me explain. Wherever, we have missing values, we have to add the proceeding and next available value and divide it by the number of missing values.

Comment: So you just need to fill in the blank spaces with averages?

Answer (score 0):

```
def curve_smoothing(string):
    
    S=string.split(',')       #Splitting the string, storing it in new variable
    index=0                   #initialising index variable to track current index  
    
    while index<len(S)-1:
        
        if S[index] =='_':    #Handling the case where first element is '_' 
            for i in range(index,len(S)):
                if S[i]!='_':     #when first number traced
                    S[index:i+1]=[int(S[i])//(i-index+1) for x in range(index,i+1)]
                    index=i
                    break
            else:             #If string only contains '_' , return 0
                S[index:len(S)]=[0 for x in range(len(S))]
        
        else:                 #When first number is not '_'                   
            if S[index+1]!='_':       #If numbers found at consecutive position, iterate index by 1
                index=index+1
            for i in range(index+1,len(S)):    #Handling the case when there are '_' between two numbers    
                if S[i]!='_':
                    S[index:i+1]=[(int(S[index])+int(S[i]))//(i-index+1) for x in range(index,i+1)]
                    index=i
                    break
            else:                 #If the only number present in list is at 0th index and rest elements are '_' 
                S[index:len(S)]=[int(S[index])//(len(S)-index) for x in range(index,len(S))]
    return S

S=  "_,_,_,_,50"
smoothed_values= curve_smoothing(S)
print(smoothed_values)
```

Comment: Covers all the use cases. Could have replaced two identical if conditions with a function but this looks more intuitive. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**code**

```
def getStr(st):
    s = st.split(',')
    k = {}
    counter = 0
    lstcounter = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i].isdigit():
            if lstcounter != i:
                k[counter] = (lstcounter,i)
                counter = counter + 1
                lstcounter = i

        if lstcounter < len(s):
            if lstcounter != len(s)-1:
                k[counter] = (lstcounter,len(s)-1)
    
    return k

def getCal(s,d):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(d)):
        firstIndex = d[i][0]
        secondIndex = d[i][1]
        first_ele = str(s[d[i][0]])
        second_ele = str(s[d[i][1]])

        if first_ele.isdigit() and second_ele.isdigit():
            for j in range(firstIndex, secondIndex + 1):
                s[j] = ((int(first_ele) + int(second_ele)) // (secondIndex - firstIndex + 1))

        elif second_ele.isdigit():
            for j in range(firstIndex, secondIndex + 1):
                s[j] = (( int(second_ele)) // (secondIndex - firstIndex + 1))
        elif first_ele.isdigit():
            for j in range(firstIndex, secondIndex + 1):
                s[j] = (( int(first_ele)) // (secondIndex - firstIndex + 1))
    return s



def getSmootString(string):
    
    indexes = getStr(string)
    lst = getCal(string.split(','),getStr(string))
    
    return lst


a =  "_,_,30,_,_,_,50,_,_"
b = "40,_,_,_,60"
c = "_,_,_,24"
d = "80,_,_,_,_"
e = "10_,_,30,_,_,_,50,_,_,20"


print(getSmootString(a))
print(getSmootString(b))
print(getSmootString(c))
print(getSmootString(d))
print(getSmootString(e))
```

**output**

[10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 4, 4, 4]

[20, 20, 20, 20, 20]

[6, 6, 6, 6]

[16, 16, 16, 16, 16]

[10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 8, 8, 8, 8]

Comment: Please write a small descriptive text, so the answer doesn't only contain code.